# Access texture that has been altered through texture nodes

Tags: texturing, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I have created a texture brush (not a cycles one) and then transformed it in various ways by going into the texture node editor and using nodes. My node tree consists of a cloud texture from the textures node menu, then several mixes and changes, and then ends with an output node.

I want to use this modified texture in the compositor. However, when I use a texture input node and select the texture I made, I only get the default clouds, and none of the changes made by my other nodes.

How do I get the full results from the texture nodes?

EDIT: Well I opened the file again this morning and now it's all working properly. I have no clue why it wasn't before. So guess this question should be deleted?

Comment: Could you post your Compositor and Texture brush's node setups?

Comment: Well I opened the file again this morning and now it's all working properly. I have no clue why it wasn't before. So guess this question should be deleted?

Comment: @Drudge no need to delete your question. It may help others in the future that do not know how to use texture nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with Node Editor, you are actually creating a new texture.

Check whether the texture name in the *ToolShelf* corresponds to the texture block.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have a **brush texture** as in the image below:

[image]

You'll just have to recall the same texture in the compositor with the **texture node**.

[image]

There are no issue with both Blender Render and Cycles even with more complex node trees.

[image]